# Prevent list display filter from resetting v-list selection

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Version info: `Vuetify 2.6.3, Vue 2.6.14, Nuxt 2.15.8`

I'm making a custom component that is supposed to be somewhat similar to `v-autocomplete`, except that it's rendered as bottom sheet. If user enters a display filter into `v-text-field`, the option list (`v-list`) is supposed to display only those options that match the filter.

In overall it works fine except one use case: let say the list has 5 items (aa, bb, cc, dd, ee) and user selected `bb` and `cc` from the list. Now, `v-list-item-group`'s model `selectedItems` contains the 2 selected items `bb` and `cc`, perfect! However, when user enters `b` into display filter, the already selected item `cc` will be auto deleted from `selectedItems`. I can't tell if `selectedItems` change is caused by filter or by user selection. **Is there a way to maintain the selection in model?**

I'm considering a hack - if an item is selected, keep it in `filteredChoices` even if it does not match the filter. This behaviour is bearable but UX wise not as intuitive as the filter of `v-autocomplete`.

The *simplified structure* looks like the below:

```
<template>
  <v-bottom-sheet scrollable>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item-group
              v-model="selectedItems"
              :mandatory="!optional"
              :multiple="multiple"
          >
            <v-list-item
                v-for="item in filteredChoices"
                :key="item.value"
                :value="item"
            >
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-text-field
          v-model="filterInput"
          placeholder="filter choices..."
          hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card>
  </v-bottom-sheet>
</template>

<script>
  ...
  filteredChoices() {
    if (this.filterInput == null) {
      return this.allItems
    }

    return this.allItems.filter((item) => {
      return item.label
          .toLocaleLowerCase()
          .includes(String(this.filterInput).toLocaleLowerCase())
    })
  },

  ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How I reach the solution:

I was quite new to front-end stuff. Previously, when I was learning how to implement `v-model` support for custom component, all web resources I came across say the same thing - bind inner component's `value` props to custom component's `value` props. However I just discovered that this is merely one of the ways rather than a must. With that new learning, more possibilities pop up in my mind and one of them lead me to below solution.

### Solution:

#### Decouple the custom component value from bottomsheet's list

1. Bind the model of inner `v-autocomplete` to an array data, say `internalValue`. (this inner component is not included in question's template for simplification)
2. Bind the model of inner `v-list-item-group` (in bottomsheet) to a separate data, say `bottomSheetSelections`.

#### Update the custom component value based on user actions in bottomsheet

1. Add a watcher to `bottomSheetSelections` array:

   - if the array grows, it means the user has selected more item. We should push the additional item to `internalValue`.
   - if the array shrinks:

     - if the missing item is still there in `filteredChoices`, the removal is triggered by user de-selection. We should remove this item from `internalValue`.
     - else, we consider the removal is triggered by list filter. No action is needed.

#### Restore user selection in bottomsheet on clearing filter

1. Add a watcher for `filteredChoices`. Whenever the array grows, if the additional choice exist in `internalValue`, we should push it to `bottomSheetSelections`.

### Summary

1. Strictly speaking, this doesn't solve the ask of question's title - the list selection in bottomsheet (bound to `v-list-item-group`) is still getting reset. However, at least we're able to restore it in bottomsheet on clearing filter.
2. More importantly, this solution achieved the objective mentioned in question details - retain the user selection value. We kept it in a separate data `internalValue`.
3. I haven't test this solution with long list of data. My guts feeling is that there could be more efficient solution. Please share it if you have a better solution.